# How can I pass an ID across function views and CBV? - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-formwizard

Sorry for such a rookie question, but I'm stuck and I'm reaching out. I've used the FormWizard to capture subscription data from users. Works great. Now I want them to be able to update their subscription using the same FormWizard.

I'm able to show their previous inputs, however, when it comes to actually knowing which record to update, that's where I'm having trouble. I am able to get the `id` from the URL in the view function for that path, but I'm having trouble getting the `id` to other views.

My code is below. I'm stuck on section 9.3. I'm not sure how to get the record `id` so it can update the correct record. If there is a better approach, feel free to suggest it and thanks in advance.

urls.py

```
path('subscription/update/<int:id>/', service_views.wizard_edit, name='wizard-edit'),
```

views.py

```
## 9.1 Displaying the data in the form
def wizard_edit(request, id):

    ##  Collecting the data
    sub = Subscribers.objects.get(id=id)

    ## Displaying the data in the appropriate forms
    initial = {
       '0': {'industry_search':sub.industry},
       '1': {'city':sub.city, 'kilometers':sub.kilometers, 'street_1':sub.street_1, 'street_2':sub.street_2},
       '2': {'email':sub.email}
       }

    wiz = ContactWizardUpdate.as_view([ContactForm1, ContactForm2, ContactForm3], initial_dict=initial)
    return wiz(request)

## 9.2 FormWizard
class ContactWizardUpdate(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'service/subscribe.html'
    form_list = [ContactForm1, ContactForm2, ContactForm3]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

        ## Function to update the DB and save data
        update_the_form_data(self, form_list)

        return render(self.request, 'service/done.html')

## 9.3 Updating the database with the changes
def update_the_form_data(self, form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

    ## Get the correct record for the update
    foo = get_object_or_404(Subscribers, id=[THE ID FOR THE RECORD])

    ## Additional code

    foo.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it. I'll share in case this helps someone else.

Instead of having the path on the urls.py file:
`path('subscription/update/<int:id>/', service_views.wizard_edit, name='wizard-edit'),`

I changed it to, `path('subscription/update/', service_views.wizard_edit, name='wizard-edit'),` and added an edit button on the user's subscription summary page with the following path, `<a href="DOMAIN.COM/subscription/update/?id={{ detail.id }}">Edit Subscription</a>`

Here are the edits to the views.py file:

```
## 9.1 Displaying the data in the form
def wizard_edit(request):  ## NEW
    id_ = request.GET.get('id')  ## NEW

    ##  Collecting the data
    sub = Subscribers.objects.get(id=id_)  ## NEW

    ## Displaying the data in the appropriate forms
    initial = {
       '0': {'industry_search':sub.industry},
       '1': {'city':sub.city, 'kilometers':sub.kilometers, 'street_1':sub.street_1, 'street_2':sub.street_2},
       '2': {'email':sub.email}
       }

    wiz = ContactWizardUpdate.as_view([ContactForm1, ContactForm2, ContactForm3], initial_dict=initial)
    return wiz(request)

## 9.2 FormWizard
class ContactWizardUpdate(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'service/subscribe.html'
    form_list = [ContactForm1, ContactForm2, ContactForm3]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

        ## Function to update the DB and save data
        update_the_form_data(self, form_list)

        return render(self.request, 'service/done.html')

## 9.3 Updating the database with the changes
def update_the_form_data(self, form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

    id_ = self.request.GET.get('id') ## NEW
    ## Get the correct record for the update
    foo = get_object_or_404(Subscribers, id=id_)  ## NEW

    ## Additional code

    foo.save()
```